# Grimmett and Stirzaker Exercise 3.11.23

Tags: probability

Consider a symmetric random walk with:

Absorbing barrier at N
Reflecting barrier at 0, (so that , when the particle is at zero, it moves 1 at the next step)
$\alpha_k(j)$ probability that the particle, having started at k, visits 0 exactly j times before being absorbed at N. If k=0 then the starting point counts as one visit.

It has been shown previously that the probability that the particle hits 0 before N is $(1-\frac{k}{N})$. Therefore

$P(M \geq r|S_0=k)=(1-\frac{k}{N})(1-\frac{1}{N})^{r-1}$

This much is straightforward.

Then:
\begin{align}
P(M = j|S_0=k)&=P(M \geq j|S_0=k)-P(M \geq j+1|S_0=0) \\
              &=(1-\frac{k}{N})(1-\frac{1}{N})^{j-1} - (1-\frac{1}{N})^{j+1}\\
              &=(1-\frac{k}{N})(1-\frac{1}{N})^{j-1}\frac{1}{N}
\end{align}

Is the second line above correct?

If so how so they go from the second line to the third line?